# Android Studio - get error: java.util.zip.ZipException: only DEFLATED entries can have EXT descriptor

Tags: android, compilation, zip, android-studio

I'm using Android Studio. I get this error at compilation:

```
java.util.zip.ZipException: only DEFLATED entries can have EXT descriptor
```

What does it mean.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One of the jar library files has been compressed in an unusual way.

Decompress the offending jar archives (you may have to rename to `.jar` to `.zip` before you can do this). Then recompress (I use 7-Zip archiver). Make sure you compress as zip, use compression level `"store"`, and make sure the folder hierarchy remains the same. Remember to rename `.zip` back `.jar`.

Answer (score 4):

In case this helps anybody; this exception usually happens when using a native Java ZipInputStream to unpack a ZIP file with a 0-byte entry.

Answer (score 2):

This error also occurs when the zipped format is not compatible with the OS. Extract the zip file using the OS zipping tool, and zip it back using the OS zipping tool resolves the issue.

Answer (score 0):

On Linux, `7z x` allowed me to open such a `.zip` file.

Whereas previously, this file was yielding the error `only DEFLATED entries can have EXT descriptor` when attempting to extract its contents with the default `unzip %x`.

Be careful though, unlike `unzip %x` which creates a new directory, `7z x` will extract in the current directory.